# Disallow ListView to have zero selected items

Tags: c#, winforms, listview

My project is .NET/WinForms.

I have a list view which is always filled with items. I would like it to have selection always. However, if I click on an empty area below list view items, it looses selection.

The list has multiple selection = true and hide selection = false.

Comment: duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2382369/prevent-listview-to-lose-selected-item

Comment: Duplicate subject only.  That thread doesn't have a real answer.

Comment: And that thread's highest updvoted answer is for WPF,  this is WinForms.

Comment: there is a very simple way...in listview properties set HideSelection to false and FullRowSelect to true.@Alex

Answer (score 29, accepted):

You need to prevent the native control from seeing the mouse click so it won't unselect an item.  Add a new class to your project and paste the code shown below.  Compile.  Drop it from the top of the toolbox onto your form, replacing the existing one.

```
using System;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Windows.Forms;

class MyListView : ListView {
    protected override void WndProc(ref Message m) {
        // Swallow mouse messages that are not in the client area
        if (m.Msg >= 0x201 && m.Msg <= 0x209) {
            Point pos = new Point(m.LParam.ToInt32());
            var hit = this.HitTest(pos);
            switch (hit.Location) {
                case ListViewHitTestLocations.AboveClientArea :
                case ListViewHitTestLocations.BelowClientArea :
                case ListViewHitTestLocations.LeftOfClientArea :
                case ListViewHitTestLocations.RightOfClientArea :
                case ListViewHitTestLocations.None :
                    return;
            }
        }
        base.WndProc(ref m);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion but it is a bit too low-level. I think I will go for manual setting selection back as suggested below.

Comment: Odd, I'd consider "manually setting selection back" a low-level hack.

Comment: This is a great solution but I had to make it a public class to get it to work.

Answer (score 4):

This following works if you do not need multiselect. It has the advantage of not needing to to track which item was last selected.

```
private void ListViewAny_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if ((sender as ListView).FocusedItem != null)
    {
        (sender as ListView).FocusedItem.Selected = true;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Like the others have said, the `SelectedIndexChanged` event is what you should look at, however you should use it in collaboration with the `ItemSelectionChanged` event. Here's some code I've just cooked up:

```
// Holds the last selected index
private int _previousIndex = -1;

// Restores the previous selection if there are no selections
private void listView1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (listView1.SelectedIndices.Count == 0)
    {
        if (_previousIndex >= 0)
        {
            listView1.SelectedIndices.Add(_previousIndex);
        }
    }
}

// Records the last selected index
private void listView1_ItemSelectionChanged(object sender, 
               ListViewItemSelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.IsSelected)
    {
        _previousIndex = e.ItemIndex;
    }
}
```

For pure code re-use purposes, it'd probably be worthwhile putting this code into a new UserControl and have a property that determines whether or not to allow the last selection to be lost:

```
public class CustomListView : ListView
{

    protected CustomListView()
    {
        this.SelectedIndexChanged += new EventHandler(CustomListView_SelectedIndexChanged);
        this.ItemSelectionChanged += new ListViewItemSelectionChangedEventHandler(CustomListView_ItemSelectionChanged);
    }

    void CustomListView_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (this.MaintainLastSelection && this.SelectedIndices.Count == 0)
        {
            if (_previousIndex >= 0)
            {
                this.SelectedIndices.Add(_previousIndex);
            }
        }
    }

    void CustomListView_ItemSelectionChanged(object sender, ListViewItemSelectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.IsSelected)
        {
            _previousIndex = e.ItemIndex;
        }
    }

    private int _previousIndex = -1;

    public bool MaintainLastSelection
    {
        get { return _maintainLastSelection; }
        set { _maintainLastSelection = value; }
    }
    private bool _maintainLastSelection;

}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
    private void LV_MouseUp(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        if (LV.FocusedItem != null)
        {
            if (LV.SelectedItems.Count == 0)
                LV.FocusedItem.Selected = true;
        }
    }
```

(no multiselect)

Answer (score 0):

You need to handle the `SelectedIndexChanged` event of the ListView and in case there is no  item selected after this event occurs, programmatically re-select the last known selection.

Answer (score 0):

The `ListView` has a `SelectedIndexChanged` event.  Listen for this and then query the `listView.SelectedItems.Count` property - if it's zero, select the first / last selected item.