# Listview has no item selected , when we click at the empty area in the listview c#

Tags: c#

I have found some solution for this in the link below. 
[Disallow ListView to have zero selected items](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3255046/disallow-listview-to-have-zero-selected-items)

My issue is when user clicks at the empty area in list view. the below line throws null exception.

```
string x = lvwIngred.SelectedItems[0].Name;
```

I want to use this below code before executing the above line.

sample-

```
if (lvwxyz.FocusedItem != null)
    {
        lvwxyz.FocusedItem.Selected = true;
    }
string x = lvwIngred.SelectedItems[0].Name
```

It works fine if I use the above approach. I have set hideselection = true; multiselect = false;

First Question is - Will it work if hideselection property is set to true for all cases.
2nd Question - What will be the scenario when the lvwxyz.FocusedItem is null, and how can we fix that scenario.

I have also used `lvwxyx.Items[0].Selected = true;` This also fixes the issue.

Please help.

Comment: Why don't you check SelectedItems == null?

Comment: From your question I believe you are trying to store a null value in string x. Since your SelctedItem[0].Name attributedoesnt have a value hence the error. Implement a check for null before u  access the value

Comment: @Jerin no, strings are nullable in .NET, so there is no issue with assigning null to a string type (hence `string.IsNullOrEmpty`, etc.) If it's really throwing `NullReferenceException`, that would indicate that `SelectedItems` itself is null, otherwise it would throw `ArgumentOutOfRangeException` if the list was empty (i.e. no item at index 0).

Comment: @aardila yes strings are nullable what I meant by novalue is if the 0th element doesnt have Name attribute itself present or else as you said no item at index 0.

Comment: I can not do null check, I need the value, i.e. I need the item which was selected in the listview, even if the focus is not present in the item.

Comment: I don't need null lvwIngred.SelectedItems[0], I need the value, even if I click the empty space in the listview. The last focused item should be available in lvwIngred.SelectedItems[0]

Comment: Answer to first question: try it. Second question: If you click in the empty space, then obviously no item will be focused. So, please define what you would expect as a user. Which item should be selected...the last? the first? And if you can answer that, just select the item you want.

Comment: thanks for the response Rene, but if you click on empty space then the lvwxyz.FocusedItem. holds the last selected item value.

Comment: Can't we add a list view click event and have these code changes there itself.