# Maintain listview row selected

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2008

I already check this question - [prevent listview to lose selected item](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2382369/prevent-listview-to-lose-selected-item) . 
but I need this code for VB.Net. I already used c# to vb converter and the output is this.

```
Private Sub ListView_SelectionChanged(sender As Object, e As SelectionChangedEventArgs)
    Dim listView As ListView = TryCast(sender, ListView)
    If listView.SelectedItems.Count = 0 Then
        For Each item As Object In e.RemovedItems
            listView.SelectedItems.Add(item)
        Next
    End If
End Sub
```

And the error is : `'SelectionChangedEventArgs' is not defined.`

I replaced the `SelectionChangedEventArgs` to `ByVal e As System.EventArgs`

and now the error is:
`'RemovedItems' is not a member of 'System.EventArgs'.`

`Property: HideSelection = False` also not working for me.

How will I able to maintain the row selected?

Comment: I'm confused what do you need. You mention you want to keep a row selected but on what condition?

Comment: Have you tried 'e As System.Windows.Controls.SelectionchangedEventArgs' or Imports System.Windows.Controls ?